# Does anyone know what this SMD IC labelled "HuANA" is? I'm having a hard time finding its datasheet on the internet

Tags: identification, bluetooth-low-energy, controller

I am troubleshooting a Xiaomi M365 e-scooter. After checking for problems in the dashboard, I found the BLE controller's supply pin is grounded/shorted with the ground. I found this SMD IC "HuANA" causing the problem.  It is faulty. I want to replace or look for alternative, but I can't find any info on it on the internet. Please help me identify what IC this is.

[image: Photo of PCB showing unidentified device]

Comment: You need a better, sharp picture of a larger area around the chip for people to guess what its for.  The markings are probably useless as it is either special order or uniquely marked.  Your yellow circle is also making it kind of hard to see where some of the traces go.

Comment: why don't you clean the board before deciding that some component is defective?

Comment: Have you looked it up on the internet: there URL is: https://www.mi.com/us/mi-electric-scooter from there you can get manuals etc, warranty support. Ask they may have a replacement board or even a schematic, you never know until you ask!

Comment: The marking "HuANA" is not a part number, you may as well quit looking for it on the internet, unless you find a schematic you are not going to identify which exact component it is... Best you can hope to do is to identify which type of component it is and based on some reverse-engineering maybe find a suitable replacement..

Answer (score 2):

It's a [Silergy SY7310AADC](https://max.book118.com/html/2020/0726/5224312042002322.shtm) (partial datasheet link, also [this](https://www.silergy.com/cn/productsview/SY7310AADC)) boost converter LED driver.

There are similar boost LED-driver ICs from other manufacturers such as AP3032 from Diodes Inc.

Photo from [here](https://m.1688.com/offer/677008829229.html):

[image]

Everything after the 'Hu' or 'HuA' is likely a date code. Other [reported number](https://electro.club/m/100558)s for this part are HuAPA, Hu6CA, HuASA.

Answer (score 0):

This is front led light driver. Ic name is AL5801

Comment: Please provide some evidence that this is the case.

Comment: Mishania Sol - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. However page 10 in the [datasheet for the AL5801](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AL5801.pdf) mentioned in your answer, states that it has a top marking of `L100`. That doesn't match the top marking of the device in the question. So, as commented, please can you explain how you decided the device shown in the question is an AL5801? Thanks.

Comment: This datasheet is for 2012. The LED driver has many markings and analogues. Even the ble led driver for this scooter has various markings.